# Wordpress page dynamic content

Tags: php, wordpress

i'm hoping someone can assist, with setting up a dynamic page in wordpress

We currently have thousands of images but i don't want these setup as posts, tho i still want them within the wordpress site, so I'm wondering is it possible to create a page domain.com/newpage and if accessed via domain.com/newpage?funny it would display the image funny.jpg from another directory on the server

Obviously id need to setup a custom page template which i can do but im struggling with the dynamic code bit

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can add images under **Media** in Admin. They would not be linked to a post but they can be used throughout the site.

Comment: +1 ... although _technically_ those media files there are posts, just of special post type called _attachment_.